# Correct null relationship in JSON API

Tags: json, json-api

I have a [JSON API](https://jsonapi.org/) type with a relationship

```
relationships {
    fruit: {data: {id: 123, type: "fruits"}}
}
```

What do I do if an instance does not have a fruit relationship?

Should I do this

```
relationships {
    fruit: {data: {id: null, type: "fruits"}}
}
```

or this

```
relationships {
    fruit: {data: null}
}
```

or this

```
relationships {
    fruit: null
}
```

or something completely different?

Comment: So what exactly is your question ?? here?

Comment: I tried to clarify. Is it still obscure?

Comment: Please stop voting this as opinionated. Their is only one correct answer cause this question is not about any REST API that serves JSON but about [JSON:API specification](https://jsonapi.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accordingly to the spec a resource linkage object may have these values:

> Resource linkage MUST be represented as one of the following:
>
> - null for empty to-one relationships.
> - an empty array ([]) for empty to-many relationships.
> - a single resource identifier object for non-empty to-one relationships.
> - an array of resource identifier objects for non-empty to-many relationships.
>
> https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-linkage

From your examples only

```
"relationships": {
    "fruit": {
      "data": null
    }
}
```

is a valid [relationship object](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-relationships) accordingly to JSON:API specification.

This relationship object tells your client that

- the [resource object](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-objects) has a relationship `fruit`,
- that it's a *to-one* relationship,
- and that there isn't any related resource.